# Read arguments separated by newline

Tags: shell-script, shell, arguments, newlines

I have a script and I receive data from stdin as an argument separated by newlines say I have

```
string1,string2
string3,string4
```

And I want to take sperately `string1,string2` and `string3,string4`.
But I receive an unknown number of such lines, my script only reads the first 2 and then stops. I tried parsing `\n` from stdin but it does not work.How should I approach this?

I tried reading like this

```
for i in "$@" 
do 
var1=$(echo "$i" | cut -f2 -d,) 
var2=$(echo "$i" | cut-f2 -d,)
#etc
```

What I am actually trying to accomplish is say I have a file `input.txt` with that type of input:

```
string1,string2
string3,string4
```

If I do `cat input.txt | ./myscript.sh` I want to take, no matter how many lines of strings I have I want to take each line and extract from it in 2 variables `stringI,stringJ` respectively.

Comment: And what did you try?

Comment: @muru I tried reading like this ```for i in "$@" do var1=$(echo "$i" | cut -f2 -d,) var2=$(echo "$i" | cut-f2 -d,)```

Comment: But it does not work since there is only 1 arguments am i right?

Comment: You aren't reading anything from stdin in that code, that I can see. Please edit in the code to your question.

Comment: What do you mean? I am reading from stdin, I tried it myself

Comment: @C.Cristi: Your attempt looks like you are reading in positional arguments and not from standard input

Comment: @Inian because that's what I should do actually, read them as arguments from keyboard....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's to do text processing, then the most obvious is to use `awk` which is especially designed for that (though `perl` or `sed` could also be used)

```
awk -F, '{print "something with "$1" and "$2}'
```

If the input is actual CSV which could have more complex values like:

```
"field, with comma" , "and with
newline", "or ""quotes"""
```

You may want to use `perl` or `python` or some dedicated csv parsing utilities.

If the fields have to be made available as shell variables, because for instance you need to run some specific commands with those fields as arguments, then you'd do something like:

```
while IFS=, read -r a b rest; do
   something-with "$a" "$b"
done
```

See also GNU `parallel` to run things in parallel:

```
PARALLEL_SHELL=sh parallel -C, 'something-with {1} {2}'
```

But beware GNU `parallel` brings a significant overhead so the parallelisation has to be worth it.

The `ksh93` shell can actually understand the CSV format (handle quoting of individual fields like in the complex example above)

```
while IFS=, read -rS a b rest; do
   do-something-with "$a" "$b"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you can use read with -d option which takes multi-line user input.

or use `tr '\n' ' '` to translate new line to space this is hacky.

I don't know a way but you can use tr to translate EOF to new line so it will fir perfect in your expectation.

feel free to comment if you need more specifics.

Answer (score 0):

If (for some reason) you want to slurp up all the input lines into an array, in bash you use

```
readarray -t input_lines
```

and then each line is stored as an element of the indexed array `input_lines`. The `-t` is to strip the newline from each line.